# Get values from the last JSON object

Tags: json, vba, excel

In VBA I use the following JSON Converter https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON to parse through simple JSON responses.

However, I have a JSON response that has multiple objects and I wish for my code to always take the value in the last (ie. more recent) object.

Here is my JSON :

```
[
  {
    "masterDataID": 26941,
    "testRunID": 66929
  },
  {
    "masterDataID": 26941,
    "testRunID": 67485
  },
  {
    "masterDataID": 26941,
    "testRunID": 67926
  }
]
```

As you can see, there is no apparent name to the objects, so I am forced to use numbers to designate them.

Here is my code :

```
Public Sub GETID()

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Dim URL As String

URL = Range("B3")

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", URL, False
http.send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)

ID = JSON(1)("testRunID")

Range("B4") = ID

End Sub
```

In

```
ID = JSON(1)("testRunID")
```

JSON(1) gets me the first object (ie. ID = 66929) However I wish to get the last object no matter how many objects there are (maybe by counting the number of objects and doing +1)...I'm afraid my knowledge of VBA is very basic :s

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: I actually saw this answer somewhere but thought it was too simple haha, thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your JSON object is a Collection of Dictionaries (each dictionary represents an object element in the source JSON array)

Collection has a `Count` property so this will give you what you want:

```
ID = JSON(JSON.Count)("testRunID")
```

Comment: So the index and count are both 1 based? A standard VBA dictionary has a zero-based index and a one-based count (without modifying).

Comment: Collection not Dictionary